# Get HoloEverywhere working alongside ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to write an app for a local school event.  Since I need it for such a broad audience, I need to make sure the app is compatible with android 2.3+ at a minimum.  I'd never used ActionBarSherlock or Holoeverywhere, but now seems like the time.

ActionbarSherlock is working.  I was able to make a Sherlock Activity, no problem.  However, HoloEverywhere is giving me 24 errors.  Some of them seem to be that Holoeverywhere isn't seeing ActionbarSherlock.  Every style that references .Sherlock has an error stating

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name `[parentname]`
```

This is in both /res/values/styles.xml and /res/values-v14/styles.xml

The rest of the errors are com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere trying to reference android.R.  It can't be resolved, and attempting to import android.R in those files (DialogHolo, DialogAlertBuilder, and HoloToast) just gets me another error because the R.ids that those classes are trying to reference do not exist.

I installed HoloEverywhere by downloading the .zip from his github, extracting the zip, and making a library project out of `ChristopheVersieux-HoloEverywhere-148b903/HoloEverywhereLib`.  This worked fine for ActionbarSherlock.  I also tried to clone his git repo, and I can see it in my Git Repositories view in eclipse, but it doesn't show up as a possible library when I do that.

Anyone know how to get HoloEverywhere working?

Comment: HoloEverywhere doesn't have any dependency with ABS since v2.0. So you wont need ABS anymre.ABS further developement is stopped because of actionbarcompat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20895081/623694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to file this one under bizarre eclipse behavior.

After spending about an hour trying to fix it, cleaning builds, etc, posting the question, and then spending about 20 more minutes trying to get it working, I went to go have some quick dinner.  Came back, and all the errors had disappeared.  This continued after a reboot and a project cleaning.  If you have this error, try waiting a bit.  Maybe it just needs time to work everything out.

Comment: Maybe the issue was related to lint warnings that had not been cleared?

Answer (score 3):

I had an error with HoloEverywhere that tons of resources couldn't be found. I added the ActionBarSherlock Library to HoloEverywhere and that fixed it all. Maybe that was it?